# Laravel Get Collection From Array of IDs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an array of User IDs that I'm trying to get a collection of. I have been using the following foreach loop, but I realize that for each loop it makes, it overrides the previous data.

```
$users = DB::table('user_tags')->where('tag_name', $tag)->whereNotNull('user_id')->lists('user_id');
$users = array_unique($users);

foreach ($users as $key => $value)
{
    $users = User::where('id', $value)->get();  
}
```

How can this return a collection with all users in that original array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's an easier way..

```
$ids = DB::table('user_tags')->where('tag_name', $tag)->whereNotNull('user_id')->lists('user_id');
$users = User::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

Comment: Q - why `whereIn` versus just `where`?

Comment: where = id | where in(array of ids)

Answer (score 0):

Is the relationship between users and tags many to many? If so, try the following query:

```
User::whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tag) {
    $query->where('tag', $tag);
})->pluck('id');
```